# Почему не работают методы map() и filter()?

Tags: javascript, angular5

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {BlogService} from '../../../../services/blog-service/blog.service';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog',
  templateUrl: './blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog.component.css'],
  providers: [BlogService]
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {
  public id: number;
  public blogs: any;

  constructor(private blog: BlogService, private activeLink: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.id = activeLink.snapshot.params['id'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.blog.getBlogs()
      .subscribe(data => this.blogs = data['blogs'])
      .map()
      .filter();
  }

}
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что они не работают?

Comment: редактор вебшторм не понимает их

Comment: @Grundy так значит я все правильно написал?

Comment: TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. вот такая ошибка появляется

Comment: какая версия rxjs?

Comment: @Grundy  "rxjs": "^6.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

Пример использования операторов можно [посмотреть в справке](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#operators).

Для применения `map` и `filter` в новых версиях rxjs нужно использовать метод `.pipe`

```
this.blog.getBlogs()
  .pipe(
      map(mapFunc),
      filter(filterFunc)
  )
  .subscribe(data => this.blogs = data['blogs']);
```

где `mapFunc` и `filterFunc` - это соответствующие коллбэки, например:

```
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const squareOdd = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  .pipe(
    filter(n => n % 2 !== 0),
    map(n => n * n)
  );
```

[Подробнее про переходе с 5 версии на 6 можно посмотреть в руководстве](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)

Comment: только вот будет ошибка `Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'`

Comment: @overthesanity, обновил ответ, subscribe Должен быть после pipe